# flex's parttern match mode

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

Recently, I am using flex to do some Lexical Analysis works, I am totally new in flex. consider the following situation, I have a multiline comment to make pattern match,

```
/**
 * 
 * multiline comment
 * 
 */
```

in flex, the regex:

```
\/\*.*\*\/
```

doesn't match this multiline comment, but just match a single line comment like:

```
/** single comment **/
```

so, it seems that flex 's pattern match is "single line mode" as grep do, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

And with this:

```
\/\*[\s\S]*\*\/
```

[explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5C%2F%5C*%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%5C*%5C%2F)

Comment: While [one line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) are acceptable, they often result in the answer being routed to the Review Queue (*q.v.*). In addition, sometimes they are not well received by the community. Its usually a good idea to provide a brief explanation that explains how the answer solves the problem.

Comment: Flex does not implement `\s` or `\S` escapes. See the [Flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

One correct Flex pattern to match multi-line C/C++ comments is: (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25396611/1566221))

```
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]
```

Flex does not provide a non-greedy repetition operator, so the above is the simplest regex which stops on the first closing `*/`. Alternatively, you can use a start condition (adapted from the [Flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#index-recognizing-C-comments)):

```
%x comment
%%

"/*"                    BEGIN(comment);

<comment>[^*]*          /* eat anything that's not a '*' */
<comment>"*"+"/"        BEGIN(INITIAL);
<comment>"*"+           /* eat up '*'s not followed by a '/' */
<comment><<EOF>>        { yyerror("Unterminated comment"); 
                          return 0;
                        }
```

Answer (score -1):

`.` in Flex matches any character *except* the newline, so instead use `(.|\n)*`. For your example:

```
\/\*(.|\n)*\*\/
```

Comment: This will match from the beginning of the first `/*` comment up to the end of the last such comment. Flex does not implement non-greedy matches, so there is no simple fix.