# Regular expression for inline comment compiler construction

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lex, analyzer, lexical

I need a regular expression for inline comment in C for a compiler's lexical analyser.
 I tried this [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zOAG.jpg)
but it is of no use as it comments out the regular expression.

[Here is simplest code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j9Ce.jpg)

Comment: Post your code as text in the question please.

Comment: Most of the part disappear as it contain lots of \\\\

Comment: It is simple Lex code for creating Tokens.

Comment: Handling comments reliably in all their glory is surprisingly hard.  In theory, you need to know about trigraphs (because `??/` maps to a backslash), but compilers like GCC ignore them by default, and C++17 eliminates them. You also need to know about backslash-newline rules; these matter, because `//` comments can continue onto subsequent lines if the last character on each line is a backslash. Both the start and end comment symbols can be broken by backslash-newline too. Most of the time, you won't run into such esoterically formatted comments, but a compiler must take them all into account.

Comment: There is a flex regular expression in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25396611/1566221) but @JonathanLeffler's comment is also correct; it depends on your having previously dealt with trigraphs and \-newline sequences before feeding the input into your lexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For catching C style comments better use start conditions. Example for flex you can find [in documentation](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html).

There is simple example for ignoring C stype comments by using exclusive start condition:

```
%x comment
"/*"         BEGIN(comment);
<comment>[^*\n]*        /* eat anything that's not a '*' */
<comment>"*"+[^*/\n]*   /* eat up '*'s not followed by '/'s */
<comment>"*"+"/"        BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but I need the regular expression for "//" inline comments

Comment: My code is working fine for block comments. why I need to use this (your one) method?

Comment: For one line comments you need put your regular expression (something like `"//".*\n`) **before** rule what ignore newline `[ \t\n]+`

Comment: @komar: There is no need to put those two rules in any particular order, since they cannot both match at any point in the input. Also, it is certainly not necessary to use a state machine to ignore block comments; a simple regular expression suffices.